# Django admin and a lot of foreign keys

Tags: django

**Django==1.11.5**

Could you help me with admin site. I have a lot of models related to each other as one-to-many:

```
 Frame
   |
    \Item
     |   \
     |    \
     |     \
     |      \
     |       \Sheet      
     |            |  
      \ItemFile   |\Image
                  |
                  |\File
                  |
                  \Note
```

Well, a frame contains many items etc. Let's illustrate just by these three models and their admin classes:

**models**

```
class Frame(models.Model):
     pass

class Item(models.Model):
    frame = models.ForeignKey('frames.Frame',
                               blank=False,
                               null=False,
                               on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                               verbose_name=_("frame"))
class Sheet(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item,
                             on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                             verbose_name=_("item"))
```

**admin**

```
class FrameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ItemInline]

class ItemInline(admin.StackedInline):
    inlines = [SheetInline]

class SheetInline(admin.StackedInline):
    inlines = [ImageAdmin]
```

The problem is that I fail to organize a  minimally decent admin. These inline classes are not suitable. In admin if I edit a frame, items are shown. But sheets don't.

If I organize sheets through admin.ModelAdmin, then I will have to constantly switch context: create a Frame, at its edit page create items. Then go admin home, create a sheet etc.

What I would like to do. From a frame instance create an item, from item create sheet. And the values for their foreign keys should be input automatically.

Is it possible to organize that smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that implements this functionality https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline